# Running time of a sort code

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
Sort(B)
for i = 0 to (n-1)
    x = (i+1);
    for j = (i+2) to n 
        if B[x] > B[j]
           x = j;
    if x != (i+1)
       temp = B[i+1];
       B[i+1] = B[x];
       B[x] = temp;
```

What is the running time T(n)?
the problem is with the inner loop (for j = (i+2) to n )
What is the worst case scenario for the inner loop? And what is the best case? I think they are the same because it is independent, but I want to make sure.

Comment: The inner loop always has the same number of iterations for a given iteration of the outer loop, regardless of input.

Answer (score 2):

The running time is O(n^2).

Each inner loops takes `O(n-i)` time, for increasing values of `i` from 0 to `n-1`.

This gives you time complexity of:

```
T(n) <= CONST*(n-0 + n-1 + n-2 + ... + n-(n-1))   = 
     = CONST*(1 + 2 + ... + n) = CONST*(n(n+1)/2)
```

The last equation comes from [sum of arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

Since n(n+1)/2 is in O(n^2), this is the time complexity.

Comment: It is not the exact formula for this example, since inner loop does n-i-2. But we of course can remove that 2 as it doesn't change the whole picture. It will be something like (n*(n+1)/2) - 2*n

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri It was not supposed to give the exact formula, it's approximation with constants, I added CONST* or clarity.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer has shown the run-time of the algorithm is O(n^2). I just want to point out that the algorithm does not look completely correct to me because it fails to sort the first element (B[0] in this case) of the array.